# jQuery-ui Accordion widget, is there a condition to test if all panels are collapsed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the jQuery-ui accordion widget, which among other things displays an image depending on which panel is activated. The widget is collapsible, and I want to remove the image when all panels are collapsed.

So far my code finds the index of the active panel when it is changed, and calls a function to display the corresponding image. I think the problem is that my declaration of `index` will return 0 when the widget is collapsed, but also when the first panel is active due to the way the [options-active](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) method is set up. Is there a way to distinguish between those two states?

```
$( "#sidebar" ).accordion({ heightStyle: "content",
                            active: false,
                            collapsible: true,
                            activate: function( event, ui ) {
                                var index = $(this).accordion("option", "active");
                                if (index != false) {
                                    requestImage(index);
                                } else {
                                    removeImage();
                                }
                            }
                          });
```

If I need to create a condition that tests each panel individually like below, how would I test the state of a specific panel?

```
if ( panel 1 active || panel 2 active || panel 3 active ) {
    show image
} else {
    remove image
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The `active` option may return `false` instead of `0` when all the panels are collapsed (it is not clear in the docs), but you're using non-strict comparison so `false` and `0` are considered equivalent. Can you try `if (index !== false)` instead?

Comment: Thanks! That works. I'd already tried that (without really knowing what it meant) but there must have been something else wrong when I did. Thanks for saying what it means too, google is no good for searching operators!